# find first completely empty row on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

need a function that returns the first completely empty row (no values, no formulas, no blanks) from a sheet with sparely populated cells.  No one single column is required to be filled.

I tried this, but i can even get it to compile:

```
Public Donations As Worksheet
Set Donations = Sheets("Sheet2")

Function getEmptyRow() As Long
   Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long, maxRow As Long
   Dim col As Long
   Dim r As Variant

   lastCol = Donations.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   For col = 1 To lastCol Step 1
      lastRow = Donations.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
      maxRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(maxRow, lastRow)
   Next col
   getEmptyRow = maxRow + 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Using EntireRow (which is so useful let me tell you) and counting row by row starting in A1 is one very basic way of doing this.

This will tell you in the immediate window:

```
Sub findemptyrow()                       '''Psuedo Code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False       'turns off annoying blinky
Range("a1").Activate                     'start at beginning   
While a <> 1                             'keep going
  If Application.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow) = 0 Then  'is it blank?
  Debug.Print "Row " & (ActiveCell.Row) & " is blank."   'it is
  a = 1                                   'stop going  
  End If
  ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate           'next cell
Wend                                      'do it all over again  
Application.ScreenUpdating = True         'back to normal settings
End Sub
```

Making `ScreenUpdating` False will make this faster, even with 10k's of rows.

Answer (score 0):

The [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) is likely the most expedient method. Look for a wildcard (`What:=Chr(42)`), start in A1 (`After:=.Cells(1, 1)`, search backwards  (`SearchDirection:=xlPrevious`), search row-by-row (`SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row`), look at the formulas (`LookIn:=xlFormulas`) since that will find the first value or formula; looking at `xlValues` may not be correct if a formula is returning an empty string (`""`).

```
Option Explicit
Public Donations As Worksheet

Sub test()
    Set Donations = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Debug.Print getNextEmptyRow(Donations)
End Sub

Function getNextEmptyRow(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws.Cells
        getNextEmptyRow = .Find(What:=Chr(42), After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row + 1
    End With
End Function
```

You cannot set `Donations` in the declarations area of a module code sheet. Declare the public variable in the declarations area (top) of the code sheet but Set the variable in a sub or function.

Don't forget to add 1 to the row returned if you want the *'next empty row'*.

Comment: What am I missing?  The What parameter of the find function is the character '*'  - chr(42)  when we are searching for an empty cell.

Comment: If you start at the bottom and work upwards row-by-row for the first populated cell you add 1 to the row number to get the first blank row. This is not necessarily the same as working from the top to find the first blank row as there could be a completely blank row with populated cells underneath it. The title implies the latter but the OP's code was looking for the former.

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternative using the `SpecialCells` method of a `Range:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print "Last row on Sheet1 is: " & FirstCompletelyEmptyRow(Sheet1)
End Sub

Function FirstCompletelyEmptyRow(ByRef wsTarget As Worksheet) As Long
    FirstCompletelyEmptyRow = wsTarget.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
End Function
```